# Threadsafe redis client

Tags: python, go, redis

I'm using [goredis](https://github.com/xuyu/goredis) and as far as I can see - there is a connection pool when client connects to redis server. I don't know how to query redis server and to be sure that it is in a thread-safe way.

Currently I do this:

I am creating global pointer `client`: `client *goredis.Redis`
Then I do this:

```
go func () {
    http.HandleFunc("/send_data/", trackHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/init/", initHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
} ()
```

So now I want to use `client` in `trackHandler` and `initHandler` but I am concerned that there is no syncing in any way when executing queries. Is it possible to mess-up things in this way. What is the canonical way to solve this issue in golang?

Also I am wondering how this works in [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py).
I've seen this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/m9k2DN7GX-M/5i5HtXkbeBYJ):

> In general, I suggest you either:
>
> a. create a global redis client instance and have your code use that.
> b. create a global connection pool and pass that to various redis instances throughout your code.
>
> Both of these accomplish the same thing. Both are threadsafe.

How is it done in the first scenario?

Comment: which redis client are you using? https://github.com/xuyu/goredis?

Answer (score 2):

The client has a connection pool which is thread safe, and whenever you execute a command, the client tries to get a connection from the pool. Thus even though the client has no lock, it's still thread safe, so you should be fine with a global client.

See here - how the Dial function creates a new connection pool:
https://github.com/xuyu/goredis/blob/master/redis.go#L432

And here for an example of locking in the connectino pool itself.
https://github.com/xuyu/goredis/blob/master/redis.go#L287

Re redis-py - It creates its own internal connection pool if you don't use one explicitly, so it's thread safe because under the hood the connections are pooled globally. Same thing basically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My misconceptions are about when something is considered thread-safe. Is it ok if you invoke the same function from different threads/goroutines? Are there problems only with the writes of data. I really will appreciate a more detailed answer about thread-safety in general or a link with proper materials. :)

Comment: @cldy in general - functions and everything created on the stack (temporarily during the run of a function) is considered thread safe and is not shared between threads. Once you have data that is being accessed and changed by different threads at once, things become more complicated. I suggest you just google "thread safety" and you'll find an endless suply of resources :)